# DataFrame persist does not improve performance in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a Scala script that reads from a table, transforms data and shows result using Spark. I am using Spark 2.1.1.2 and Scala 2.11.8. There is a dataframe instance I use twice in the script (`df2` in the code below.). Since dataframes are calculated when an action is called on them, not when they are declared, I predict that this dataframe to be calculated twice. I thought that persisting this dataframe would improve performance thinking that, it would be calculated once (when persisted), instead of twice, if persisted.

However, script run lasts ~10 seconds longer when I persist compared to when I don't persist. I cannot figure out what the reason for this is. If someone has an idea, it would be much appreciated.

My submission command line is below:

```
spark-submit --class TestQuery --master yarn --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 10G --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 4 /home/bcp_data/test/target/TestQuery-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Scala script is below:

```
 val spark = SparkSession
             .builder()
             .appName("TestQuery")
             .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:/tmp/hsperfdata_hdfs/spark-warehouse/")
             .enableHiveSupport()
             .getOrCreate()


 val m = spark.sql("select id, startdate, enddate, status from members")
 val l = spark.sql("select mid, no, status, potential from log")
 val r = spark.sql("select mid, code from records")

val df1 =  m.filter(($"status".isin(1,2).and($"startdate" <= one_year_ago)).and((($"enddate" >= one_year_ago)))

val df2 = df1.select($"id", $"code").join(l, "mid").filter(($"status".equalTo(1)).and($"potential".notEqual(9))).select($"no", $"id", $"code")
df2.persist

val df3 = df2.join(r, df2("id").equalTo(r("mid"))).filter($"code".isin("0001","0010","0015","0003","0012","0014","0032","0033")).groupBy($"code").agg(countDistinct($"no"))


val fa = spark.sql("select mid, acode from actions")
val fc = spark.sql("select dcode, fcode from params.codes")

val df5 = fa.join(fc, fa("acode").startsWith(fc("dcode")), "left_outer").select($"mid", $"fcode")
val df6 = df2.join(df5, df2("id").equalTo(df5("mid"))).groupBy($"code", $"fcode")

println("count1: " + df3.count + " count2: " + df6.count)
```

Comment: I believe you need to assign it to a new variable and use that, `val df2_2 = df2.presist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using caching is the right choice here, but your statement

```
df2.persist
```

has no effect because you do not utilize the returned dataframe. Just do

```
val df2 = df1.select($"id", $"code")
.join(l, "mid")
.filter(($"status".equalTo(1)).and($"potential".notEqual(9)))
.select($"no", $"id", $"code")
.persist
```

Comment: Why do you say that? In Spark >= 2.3 at least, persist *does not* return a new dataframe:https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset. You can look at the source code:
`def persist(): this.type = { sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery(this) this } `